# Apply Textures to Only Certain Faces of a Cube in Unity

Tags: c#, 3d, textures, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make realistic-looking procedurally generated buildings. So far I have made a texture generation program for them. I would like to apply that texture to a simple `cube` in Unity, however, I don't want to apply the texture to all of the faces. Currently when I apply the texture to the `cube`'s material it apply's the same texture to all of the faces and on some of the faces the texture is upside down. Do you recommend that I make `plane` objects and apply the textures to each of those (and form a cube that way). I know this would work, but is it efficient at a large scale? Or is there a way to apply different textures to individual faces of a cube in `C#`?

Comment: Why don't you instead of the chosen answer, just create your own cube mesh data for a GameObject and then apply the texture to only 1 of the faces.??

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are suggesting. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that you are trying to create buildings you should procedurally generate your own 'cube'/building mesh data.

For example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3[] newVertices;
    public Vector2[] newUV;
    public int[] newTriangles;
    void Start() {
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.vertices = newVertices;
        mesh.uv = newUV;
        mesh.triangles = newTriangles;
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
    }
}
```

Then you populate the verticies, and tris with data. 
For example, you could create a small 1 by 1 cube around origin 0 with:

```
int size = 1;
newVertices = new Vector3[]{
    Vector3(-size, -size,  -size),
    Vector3(-size,  size,  -size),
    Vector3( size,  size,  -size),
    Vector3( size, -size,  -size),
    Vector3( size, -size,   size),
    Vector3( size,  size,   size),
    Vector3(-size,  size,  size),
    Vector3(-size, -size,  size)
};
```

Then because you only want to render the texture on 1 of the meshes faces;

```
 newUV = new Vector2[]{
    Vector2(0,0), 
    Vector2(0,1),
    Vector2(1,0), 
    Vector2(1,1),
    Vector2(0,0), 
    Vector2(0,0),
    Vector2(0,0),
    Vector2(0,0),
    Vector2(0,0),
    Vector2(0,0),
    Vector2(0,0), 
    Vector2(0,0)
};
```

Note that only allocating UV coords for some of the verts This will effectively only place your desired texture on 1 of the faces and then depending on how you allocate the tris, the rest of the UVs can be altered as you see fit to appear as though they are untextured.

Please note that I wrote this with out an IDE so there may be some syntax errors. Also, this isn't the most straight forward process, but I promise that it far exceeds the use of a series of quads as a building because with this you can make a whole range of shapes 'easily'.

Resources:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GeneratingMeshGeometryProcedurally.html

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. Actually making a mesh using uvs and vertices. Definitely seems better this way (sorry MX D). Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @dsiegler19 With this method, you get total control of the assets you create without the annoyance of fiddling with quads / planes in the editor. You can even make roofs pretty easily by creating a pyramid on top of the object and then by binding it to the top corners of your building, it will effectively scale with the x and z of your building! So much potential.!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK unity does not natively support this.

There are however some easy ways to work around. Your example of using a  `plane` is a good thought, but using a `quad` would make more sense. Or even easier, create a multi faced cube as a model and export it as for example a `.fbx`

Comment: Okay thanks. When I just constructed a cube with planes in the Scene view some of them would temporarily become invisible to let you see the planes behind it. Do you know how to disable this feature?

Comment: @dsiegler19 Yes, this issue should not occur when you use `quads`. Also take note that the built-in plane has 121 vertices and 200 triangles, and a quad has 4 vertices and 2 triangles